# Many-to-Many in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two MongoDB models "Users" and "Roles". Each user can have multiple roles and each role can be assigned to many users. To keep the relation simple I would like to store the reference between both models only in the "Users" model which is already working as expected. But when I'm loading all roles at once with .find({}), I would also like to know how many users are assigned to these roles (to check if a role can be modified).

I'm using Node.js + ExpressJS and mongoose. This is what I already have:

```
  var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    ...
    roles : [ {
      type : Number,
      ref : 'Role'
    } ]
  });

  var roleSchema = new Schema({
    _id : Number,
    name : String
  });
--------------------------------------------------
  function getRoles(request, response) {
    Role.find({}, function(err, roles) {
        ....
        response.send(roles);
    });
  }
```

But now I wonder how I would achive the count query per role and still be able to send the result in one response.

I would like to avoid to send a single request per role and try to do the count within the getRoles() function. In a relational database I would do something like this:

```
select r.*,
(select count(*) from user2role u2r where u2r.role_id = r.role_id)
from role r;
```

But what's the MongoDB equivalent?

Any help and hints will be appreciated.

Thanks, Gerry

Comment: So in other words you would like to return an additional field say `userCount` i.e. the number of users for each role?

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm looking for. But even after researching for half a day I still have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the user count query per role with the given schema, you could either use the **[`count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count)** method as follows:

```
function getUsersCount(roleName, req, res) {
    Role.findOne({"name": roleName}, function(err, role) {
        var roleId = role._id;

        // var countQuery = User.where({ "role": roleId }).count();

        // User.count({ "roles": roleId }).count(callback)

        // User.count({ "roles": roleId }, callback)

        User.where({ "roles": roleId }).count(function (err, count) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log("There are %d users with the role %d", count, roleName);
            res.send(count);
        })        
    });
}
```

or you can use the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** method like:

```
// Find the user count for a given role
function getUsersCount(roleName, req, res) {
    Role.findOne({"name": roleName}, function(err, role) {
        var roleId = role._id;
        var pipeline = [
            {
                "$match": { "roles": roleId } /* filter the documents that only have the roleId in the role array */
            },
            { "$unwind": "$roles" }, 
            {
                "$match": { "roles": roleId }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": 0, "count": 1
                }
            }
        ];

        Users.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log(result); // [ { count: 55 } ] for example
            res.send(result);
        });

        // Or use the aggregation pipeline builder.
        Users.aggregate()
            .match({ "roles": roleId }) 
            .unwind("roles")
            .match({ "roles": roleId })
            .group({ "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } })
            .select("-id count")
            .exec(function (err, result) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                console.log(result); // [ { count: 55 } ] for example
                res.send(result);
            });
    });
}
```

---

-- **EDIT** --

One approach that you could take is to use the **[`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)** method to get pure JavaScript objects that you can manipulate to add the extra `userCount` field for each role. With **[`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)** it's possible because documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects', not **[MongooseDocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js)**. Thus with the roles returned from the **`find()`** cursor, you can convert them into plain JS objects
that you can iterate over using the native JavaScript **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method, get the number of users per role using another query that takes into consideration the **[`count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count)** method explained above and return the modified object.

The following demonstrates how the function is implemented:

```
function getRoles(request, response) {
    Role.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, roles) {
        var result = roles.map(function(r){
            var obj = {},
                countQuery = User.where({ "roles": r._id }).count();

            obj["userCount"] = countQuery;
            obj["_id"] = r._id;
            obj["name"] = r.name;

            return obj;
        });
        response.send(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately the new approach leads to this error message when sending the response: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON". However, I've decided to switch to the one request per role approach and count the number of users per role.

Answer (score 0):

As per your above explanation about the schema design, i can assume your schema is as below :

Roles collection :

```
 {
  role_id : 
  name : 
 }
```

User collection :

```
{
  user : 
  role_id : [ ]
  ....
}
```

you can use aggregation to achieve this :

```
 db.users.aggregate([{$unwind: "$role_id"},
 {$group: {_id: "$role_id", count : {"$sum":1}} },
 ]);
```